# Ruby -- convert array to hash with specific index

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    'date' => '2013-09-01',
    'impressions' => 50,
    'clicks' => 20,
  },
  {
    'date' => '2013-09-02',
    'impressions' => 51,
    'clicks' => 22,
  },
]
```

And I want to take one element from each array and make it the index of a hash, like this:

```
{
  '2013-09-01' => {
    'impressions' => 50,
    'clicks' => 20,
  },
  '2013-09-02' => {
    'impressions' => 51,
    'clicks' => 22,
  },
}
```

I realize I can do it by brute force, but I figured there was some magic method to help me out.  It looks like splat might be a solution, but I can't find any examples that do exactly what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you know what splat is?

Comment: I asked this some time ago. Link above. :)

Comment: Didn't find your previous question in my search.  Thanks @coreyward

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below :

```
a = [
  {
    'date' => '2013-09-01',
    'impressions' => 50,
    'clicks' => 20,
  },
  {
    'date' => '2013-09-02',
    'impressions' => 51,
    'clicks' => 22,
  },
]

Hash[a.map{|h| [h['date'],Hash[h.to_a[1..-1]]] }]
```

or

```
Hash[a.map{|h| [h['date'],h.select{|k,_| k != 'date'}] }]

# => {"2013-09-01"=>{"impressions"=>50, "clicks"=>20},
 #"2013-09-02"=>{"impressions"=>51, "clicks"=>22}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[ a.map{ |h| [ h.delete('date') , h] } ]
```